# How to set fact on Ansible based on value from inventory

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have an inventory look like this

```
host:
    vars:
        fruit:
            - {type: melon, id: 1}
            - {type: apple, id: 2}
```

currently I used to get id like below

```
list: >-
   {{groups['host']|map('extract',hostvars,'fruits')|first}} 

- set_fact:
    fruit_id: "{{list[2].id}}"
```

How can I get the id value by using type equal to apple?

Answer (score 2):

The task

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ list|
                 selectattr('type', '==', 'apple')|
                 map(attribute='id')|
                 list|first }}"
```

gives

```
    "msg": "2"
```

---

The same task in the loop

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ list|
                 selectattr('type', '==', item)|
                 map(attribute='id')|
                 list|first }}"
      loop:
        - melon
        - apple
```

gives

```yaml
    "msg": "1"
    "msg": "2"
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply, I test it 100% worked